# MSBuild exec task never completes when executing git submodule

Tags: git, msbuild, git-submodules

Within a git repository, I would like to add a sub module via MSBuild. I assumed something like the following would allow me to do so.

```
<Exec Command='git submodule add -f git@clone-url.git "sub/module/folder"' />
```

Unfortunately, the execute command never completes. The following message appears and stays until I terminate the script.

```
Cloning into 'sub/module/folder'...
```

My guess is that git is asking for my username and password. For some reason, the output is never passed to the main command window so that I can enter my username and password for the repository.

Is there anyway to see why it is pausing or allow the execute command to output to the main window?

Comment: You could try putting the command in a batch file and then calling that from Exec.

Answer (score 1):

`Exec` task inherits from `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask` which closes input stream on creation by design, e.g. threre is no input when executing under Visual Studio rather than MSBuild.

```
proc.Start();
proc.StandardInput.Close();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

To "accept" input you have to either pipe in it, or have your own custom/inline task creating the `Process` or prepend your command with `start` to escape the redirection via a new `cmd` window.

Or use an ssh key file.

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

There were attempts before to make the [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) command to ask for a password before, but this was complicated because:

> However, the `Exec` task, unlike a more specific task, cannot gather output from the tool or command that it runs.

See however "[Exec task in msbuild TFS won't execute exe properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472981/6309)"), as in a `cmd /c git submodule...`, in case that could work.